# Authenticating with the Firebase Admin SDK using environment variable

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication, firebase-admin

## The problem

When I try to use an environment variable to authenticate with Cloud Firestore, I get an ENAMETOOLONG error.  I've searched so many places for documentation.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be useful.

## Creating the environment variable

I've created an environment variable to load my service account key

`export MY_CREDENTIALS=$(cat myGoogleServiceAccountKey.json)`

## My code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = process.env.MY_CREDENTIALS;
// console.log(`Service account = ${serviceAccount}`);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();
```

## The error

When I run a node script which fetches my serviceaccount key from my environment variables, I get the following error:

```
/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:142
            throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL, 'Failed to parse certificate key file: ' + error);
            ^

Error: Failed to parse certificate key file: Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myProject",
  "private_key_id": "123456789012345678901234567890",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMy private key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-6ju1c@myProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "12345678901234567890",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-myProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}'
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:119:28)
    at Function.Certificate.fromPath (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:142:19)
    at new CertCredential (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProjecte/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:192:45)
    at Object.cert (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:237:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jason/Downloads/projects/myProject/myScript.js:7:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So when looking at the error you get, I notice it says `Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '{`. When the `admin.credential.cert` function is passed a string, it assumes you're trying to open a file with that string name. If you cast that to an object, then it should be able to read the credentials.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = process.env.MY_CREDENTIALS;
// console.log(`Service account = ${serviceAccount}`);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(JSON.parse(serviceAccount))
});

const db = admin.firestore();
```

Comment: Works like a dream.  Thanks, Jen

Comment: hey, how to store it in process.env??

Comment: what is process.env?

Comment: If you use AWS Lambdas, process.env is used to access the environment variables. These are created in the Lambdas console.