# How to access environment variables from JSON file?

Tags: json, environment-variables

I am using firebase authentication in my nextjs app. I have stored my service account credentials in a file called secret.json. I wanna hide those credentials in my next.config.js file. How can I access those credentials in the secret.json file? Maybe this will be the same approach not only for nextjs apps but also for other apps. What is the common way to achieve that or is there any specific way for nextjs app?

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

Comment: yeah, but didn't find anything about json file

Comment: how everything inside of next.config.js will be exposed if anybody gitignore this file?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider storing your private key as an environment variable, which Next.js has [built-in support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) for.  You can then avoid the risks of exposing your secrets in `next.config.js` and services like Heroku and [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) make it easy & secure to store your env vars in production.

To initialize Firebase on your server, you need just 3 things from your `secret.json` file:

- `project_id`
- `client_email`
- `private_key` - store this as an env var (e.g., FIRESTORE_PRIVATE_KEY)

You can then use the [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) package to initialize Firebase on your server:

```js
import { cert, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'

const serviceAccount = {
  projectId: 'my-project',
  clientEmail: 'myServiceAccount@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
  privateKey: process.env.FIRESTORE_PRIVATE_KEY,
}

const credential = cert(serviceAccount)

initializeApp({ credential })
```

Saving the `private_key` as its own env var will also avoid problems arising from attempting to save/parse the entire Firestore json as an env var (e.g., [ENAMETOOLONG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834843/authenticating-with-the-firebase-admin-sdk-using-environment-variable) error) and not require you to do any [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299329/node-js-firebase-service-account-private-key-wont-parse) [manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492587/escaping-issue-with-firebase-privatekey-as-a-heroku-config-variable).